# Possible caveats in using setTimeout with arguments instead of inline function definition?

Tags: javascript, syntax, arguments, settimeout

what possible caveats could be in case 2

case-1:

`setTimeout(function(){ el.removeEventListener('click', console.log, true) },  100 )`

and case-2:

`setTimeout(el.removeEventListener, 100, 'click', console.log, true)`

> I really find case-1 syntax ugly, hence the question.

Comment: @certainperformance it was deliberately put forward that way so that people don't deviate from main question, but since you are too specific, i've changed the question.

Comment: He's not being "too specific." An example should be simple, yes, but *valid*.

Answer (score 1):

Your "Case 2" will fail because `removeEventListener` will be called without any specific `this` value, and so it won't be called with `this` set to `el`. The valid comparison would be:

Case 1:

```
setTimeout(function(){ el.removeEventListener('click', console.log, true) },  100 )
```

Case 2:

```
setTimeout(el.removeEventListener.bind(el), 100, 'click', console.log, true)
// ------------------------------^^^^^^^^^
```

Which you use depends on what you want to do.

In that **specific** situation, it doesn't matter which you use provided you handle the `this` issue. But consider:

```
var x = function() { /* do something */};
el.addEventListener("click", x, false);
setTimeout(function() { el.removeEventListener("click", x, true); }, 100);
x = function() { /* do something else */};
// ...
```

That `removeEventListener` call will fail, because as of when the timer callback runs, `x` no longer refers to the function that was hooked up (it refers to a different function). But your preferred syntax:

```
var x = function() { /* do something */};
el.addEventListener("click", x, false);
setTimeout(el.removeEventListener.bind(el), 100, "click", x, true);
x = function() { /* do something else */};
// ...
```

...will work, because `x` is evaluated when you make the `setTimeout` call, not later, so it refers to the right function.

Sometimes you **want** the value of `x` later, in which case you'd use the "Case 1" form. When you want `x` evaluated right away, "Case 2" is the form you'd want to use.

---

Side note: Using `true` as the third argument to `addEventListener`/`removeEventListener` is relatively rare. It hooks (and unhooks) handlers for the *capture* phase of the event, rather than the more usual bubbling phase.